# Which framework first use view first pattern

Tags: lift

I am a scalaer, currently using the Lift framework. Lift uses the view first pattern and I would like to know from which framework did this pattern originate?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_%28web_framework%29) the pattern is based on the one used in [Wicket](https://wicket.apache.org/).